# Programatically (JAVA) Create/Delete partition from Kafka Topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka

On demand runtime, can I programatically (using java) Create/Delete partition from Kafka Topic

I am using Java Apache Kafka Client (0.10) and Apache Kafka installation (0.10)

Comment: a) what have you **tried yourself** so far? b) it wouldn't hurt you to write your questions with some question marks, would it?

Comment: I agree. Would definitely follow it from next time.

Comment: you can edit your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke AdminUtils.createTopic and AdminUtils.deleteTopic to create and delete topics respectively.

EDIT:

Use AdminUtils.addPartitions to add partitions for a topic. Kafka currently does not support to decrease the partition number.

Comment: My query is about create/delete "PARTITIONS" of a topic and not topic.